# What is ThreadProc is doing on GCroot?

Tags: .net, windbg

I'm trying to troubleshoot managed memory leak and information below does not make sense to me since I expected to see sort of static method or something like that for !gcroot command but find stuff below instead.

```
0:025> !gcroot 0000000280b0b8b8
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18444
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011
Thread 1d60:
    00000000099fe9e0 000007fef72b9376 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
        r12:  (interior)
            ->  00000003800e7948 System.Object[]
            ->  0000000180143058 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache+StoreMetadataEntry, System.Data.Entity]]
            ->  000000028076ca08 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache+StoreMetadataEntry, System.Data.Entity]][]
            ->  000000028076c970 System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache+StoreMetadataEntry
            ->  00000001808b2b70 System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection
            ->  000000028076ca68 System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection
            ->  0000000280b07428 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection1[[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction, System.Data.Entity]], mscorlib]]
            ->  0000000280b0b8b8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection1[[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction, System.Data.Entity]], mscorlib]][]
```

Found 1 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).

0:025> !threads
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18444
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011
ThreadCount:      17
UnstartedThread:  0
BackgroundThread: 17
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       0
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                                                        Lock
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
   7    1 18c0 00000000017ef3d0    28220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn 
  18    2 1b2c 000000000293ddf0    2b220 Preemptive  00000001815883A0:000000018158A328 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
  19    3  f60 0000000002991d30  102a220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  20    4  5b4 0000000002997ec0    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn 
  22    7 1748 0000000002a25f50  1020220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  25    9 1d60 00000000090f1c20  202b220 Preemptive  00000002816ECE90:00000002816EECF8 000000000299f110 1     MTA 
  26    6  8d0 0000000002abf6e0    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn 
  27   12 1e5c 0000000009174120    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn 
  28   13 1968 00000000091b65b0  1029220 Preemptive  000000018287F518:0000000182881310 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  29   11  e34 0000000002ade2b0  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  30   15  640 0000000009175fe0  8029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  31   18  b18 00000000091c1600  1029220 Preemptive  00000002824B8608:00000002824B8BA8 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  43    5 1fe8 00000000091be5d0    20220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn 
  45   20 1c7c 00000000091beda0  1029220 Preemptive  00000001826F9BA8:00000001826F9D98 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  48   14  ecc 00000000091bde00  1029220 Preemptive  0000000281874260:0000000281874270 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  53   19 1498 00000000091bd630  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
  44   17  e38 00000000091bf570    20220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000001789fc0 0     Ukn

0:025> !clrstack
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18444
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011
OS Thread Id: 0x1d60 (25)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
00000000099fe848 000000007791186a [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 00000000099fe848] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean, Boolean)
00000000099fe980 000007fef830c64c System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean)
00000000099fe9e0 000007fef72b9376 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
00000000099feab0 000007fef83bd0b5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
00000000099fec10 000007fef83bce19 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
00000000099fec40 000007fef83bcdd7 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
00000000099fec90 000007fef8330301 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
00000000099fefa8 000007fef9599e03 [GCFrame: 00000000099fefa8] 
00000000099ff2d8 000007fef9599e03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 00000000099ff2d8] 
00000000099ff4b8 000007fef9599e03 [ContextTransitionFrame: 00000000099ff4b8] 
00000000099ff6a8 000007fef9599e03 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 00000000099ff6a8]

Comment: First of all you should make sure the version of SOS matches the CLR as the error message states.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the comment, you should update the version so CLR and SOS match, as you might otherwise see incorrect output.

The stack just shows that the object is being rooted by a register (`r12` in this case) used by the code in `ThreadProc()`. Recall that an object can be rooted by the following:

- Stack/register
- GC Handle
- Finalizer queue
- Member of an object found in any of the above

Comment: What path in a code it shall take to be rooted by register? There is no unmanaged code to do that as far as I know.

Comment: The code is 64 bit which means that a lot of method arguments will be passed in registers as that is the calling convention used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: Any additional troubleshooting I can do to find what is causing this object to be not collected?

Comment: What is the object? Is it something the `ThreadProc()` method uses?

Comment: It's collection. I don't beleive code is using ThreadPool or anything so I don't understand why Thread() is there in a first place

Comment: 0:025> !do 0000000280b0b8b8
The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.
CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18444
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34011
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmFunction, System.Data.Entity]], mscorlib]][]
MethodTable: 000007feef5efa88
EEClass:     000007feef068048
Size:        10368(0x2880) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 431, Type VALU

Answer (score 0):

you can use the '.chain' command to show what DLL you have loaded. Then you can use '.unload path' to unload the unless DLL, then reload the match DLL you will resolve this issue. About how to get the match DLL, you can to check the target machine path '%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\<.NET version>' then you can get the match DLLs